# CupertinoIndicator for refreshindicator Flutter

Tags: flutter

I used RefreshIndicator wrap with singlechildscrollview it only shows circularprogressindicator in the refreshindicator. I want change to the CupertinoProgressIndicator How to do

Comment: Paste here what you did so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5):

**Flutter >=3.10 Answer**

There is a new `.adaptive()` constructor for the `RefreshIndicator` widget that does exactly what you are looking for:

```dart
RefreshIndicator.adaptive(
    onRefresh: ...
    child: ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to achieve that by using `RefreshIndicator` since it uses the *MaterialDesign* `CircularProgressIndicator`:

The **Cupertino** equivalent of `RefreshIndicator` for iOS is [CupertinoSliverRefreshControl](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSliverRefreshControl-class.html):

> `CupertinoSliverRefreshControl`, an iOS equivalent of the
> pull-to-refresh pattern. Must be used as a sliver inside a
> `CustomScrollView` instead of wrapping around a `ScrollView` because it's
> a part of the scrollable instead of being overlaid on top of it.